# How to pass <h:inputText> value to managed bean with <f:ajax>

Tags: jsf-2

I have a search function. When user input some text to `inputText` it suppose to search the text. This function I want to do with ajax function. I don't submit all the form values.

```
<td colspan="2" align="right">
    <h:inputText id="searchTxtBox" value="#{catelogue.searchTxt}">
    </h:inputText>
</td>
<td>
   <h:commandLink value="Search"><f:ajax event="click" listener="#{catelogue.findText}" render="@form"/></h:commandLink>
</td>
```

When click `Search`  button, the `searchTxt` variable in the `managed bean` is `null`.

How can I get the value to back bean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure your code is inside a **h:form** tag

2) This should be your **f:ajax** code:

```
<f:ajax execute="searchTxtBox" listener="#{catelogue.findText}" 
        render="<whatever you want to render"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tried this is working. But can you tell me what is the purpose of having '@this' attribute here?  when I remove it, still it is working.

Comment: It was superfluous.  You don't need it.  I'll go ahead and remove it.  If this answered your question, please accept the answer.